# Kendoui Grid Custom Aggregate Group Header

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, grouping

I have a purchase grid with expiration date and I need to sum only the valid values, that is, those that have not expired. The image shows what is displayed today (in red) and how it should look (in blue). Today is 2017-07-07.

[image: Exemple]

Answer (score 1):

As far I know there is no stadard kendo way to build conditional sum aggregate.
However - you can use footer template to obtain similiar functionality.

**Example:**

Column definition part:

```
columns: [
          "ColumnTitle",
          { field: "Field", title: "Title", footerTemplate: conditionalSum },
        ]
```

Function:

```
function conditionalSum() {
        var data = yourGrid.dataSource.data();
        var sum = 0;
        for (var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
          //do your calculations
        }

        return kendo.toString(sum);
      }
```